# Trying to install from source. minisat

Tags: make, install-from-source

I am trying to install the following plugin of minisat.

[link](https://github.com/niklasso/minisat-examples)

But when I go in the directory using terminal and do `make install`. It gives an error

`install -d /usr/local/bin
install -m 755 build/dynamic/bin/minumerate /usr/local/bin
install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/minumerate’: Permission denied
make: *** [install-bin] Error 1`

I tried to do what's given in README, but I can't seem to find the address $MINC and $MLIB.

I installed minisat using `sudo apt-get minisat`

How to make this source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the errors you're seeing with `make install` are because it's trying to install to a root-owned location.  You'd need to do `sudo make install` to install the program.

Secondly, if you have the `apt-get` installed version of minisat, you'll need to start by removing it, and then running the `sudo make install` to actually install the software after its built.

Comment: I did `sudo make install` and echoed `install -d /usr/local/bin
install -m 755 build/dynamic/bin/minumerate /usr/local/bin` I am not sure what you meant by removing minisat. As these examples will use the minisat libraries.